# Filterring array that is located in Json properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Hello again stackoverflow community. I have F2P component who is is 'maping' objects in json and displaying them. In that Component is located a buy Now link which leads to the payment page and Component. What should happen is this, when  I press on the Link it should display image class and name of that Component, but for some reason nothing happens. Why is that and what should I do to fix it?

```
import React from 'react'
import data from "../data.json";
import {
    
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";
function FreeToPlay({product}) {
    return (
        <>
          <div className='All' >
            {data[0].freetoplay.map((product) => {
              return (
                <div className='f2p' key={product.id}>              
                    <img src={product.image}></img>
                    <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                    <h5>{product.price}</h5>
                  <Link
            to={`/payment/${product.id}`}
            className='link'
           >
            Buy Now
           </Link>
        </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </>
      );
}

export default FreeToPlay


json
[
  {
    "freetoplay": [
      {
        "id": "0",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "60$",
        "name": "CS Go"
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "image": "src=fsdf",
        "price": "6$",
        "name": "Fifa"
      }
    ],
    {
      "action": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "image": "src=fsdf",
          "price": "60$",
          "name": "doom"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "image": "src=fsdf",
          "price": "66$",
          "name": "cyberpunk"
        }
      ],
      "adventure": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "image": "src=fsdf",
          "price": "60$",
          "name": "indiana "
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "image": "src=fsdf",
          "price": "43$",
          "name": "torchlight"
        }
      ],
    }
  ]

import React from 'react'
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import data from "../data.json";

function Payment() {
    const { productId } = useParams();
    const filteredData = data.filter((product) => product.id === productId)[0];
    return (
        <div className='Payment'>
         <img src={filteredData.image}></img>
         <h1>{filteredData.price}</h1>
         <h1>{filteredData.name}</h1>          
        </div>
    )
}
export default Payment

Routes
function Routes() {
    return (
        <div>     
        {data.map((product) => 
        <Router>                 
             <SideBar /> 
               <Route path="/payment/:productId">
             <Payment/>
             </Route>
             <Switch>
             <Route path="/action">
               <Action key={product.id} product={product} />
             </Route>             
               <Route path="/freetoplay">  
            <FreeToPlay key={product.id} product={product} />
              </Route> 
           </Switch>
    </Router>
   )}
</div>
    )
}

export default Routes
```